# how to combine latest from map of streams into map of values?

Tags: dart, stream, rxdart

I have a `Map<String, Stream<dynamic>>` and I want to convert it into a `Stream<Map<String, dynamic>>` which should yield the latest snapshot of values from the former. I need something like `Rx.combineLatest( mapOfStreams.values, (list) => list )` but somehow keeping map keys.

I've found this solution, which seems to work (supposing `keys` and `values` of `Map` are always aligned), but I feel there must be something better:

```
final keys = mapOfStreams.keys.toList();
Rx.combineLatest( mapOfStreams.values, (list) => list.asMap().map( (i, value) => MapEntry(keys[i], value) ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my way

```dart
void main() async {
  final streams = <String, Stream<dynamic>>{
    'a': Stream<int>.periodic(const Duration(milliseconds: 200), (i) => i),
    'b': Stream<int>.periodic(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), (i) => i),
    'c': Stream<String>.value('Hello'),
  };

  final final$ = Rx.combineLatest(
    streams.entries
        .map((entry) => entry.value.map((v) => MapEntry(entry.key, v))),
    (List<MapEntry<String, dynamic>> values) => Map.fromEntries(values),
  );

  final$.listen(print);

  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 10));
}
```